# What happens to location updates after Play Services restarts

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi, google-location-services

I have an IntentService that is invoked by the FusedLocationApi every minute to process locations data.

```
private void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, pendingIntent);
    }
```

If the Play Services is updated or restored from a crash, will my IntentService continue being invoked at the mentioned interval? Or will I need to re-register it?

As per my observation, on the Nexus 6P after restoring from a crash, the play services continues invoking my IntentService, but not on the Huawei Honor Bee.

In my production app, thanks to Firebase Events, I have observed that my IntentService is no longer invoked after the device runs low on memory (onTrimMemory() is called)